# What is the most resource efficient way to toggle a layers on and off?

Tags: performance, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am wondering what is the most resource efficient way to toggle layers on and off.
Should I use the `setLayoutProperty` and toggle visibility on and off, or should I use the `setPaintProperty` and toggle opacity from 0 to 1 (or any value that I want it to have)?

Comment: I don't know which is the best however if you set the opacity to 0, events will still trigger

Comment: I found this in the documentation:
"Layout properties ... are applied early in the rendering process and define how data for that layer is passed to the GPU. Changes to a layout property require an asynchronous "layout" step.

Paint properties are applied later in the rendering process... Changes to a paint property are cheap and happen synchronously."

But if you have lots of layers then would it be better to load the app in the start with them and then switch the opacity, or use both properties to compensate, depending on which layer should be used first?

Comment: Good question. I don't know, although I can tell you from experience that Mapbox-GL-JS treats an opacity of 0 quite differently from any other value (including, say, 0.01).

Comment: @SteveBennett can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I don't remember the specific cases, but when you have an opacity of 0, the layer is (or was) not rendered at all, and tiles aren't fetched. It's treated as not shown. Any opacity other than 0 causes it to be shown and tiles fetched.